# C# MySql connection cannot find host

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a java program that connects to a MySql database and it's working fine.
Now I want to convert it to a C# program, but I keep getting the error "Unable to connect to any of the specified hosts".

I've already followed the following solutions:

1. [Connect to MySql with C#](http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html)
2. [C# MySqlConnector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
3. [Configure the ODBC DNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows.html)
4. And the reference to MySql.Data has been added to the project.

Here is the code to connect to the database:

```
string connectionString = string.Format(
 "SERVER={0}; DATABASE={1}; UID={2}; PASSWORD={3};",
 "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port, dbName, userName, password);

// Prepare connecting to the database.
myConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

MySqlCommand command = myConn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM table_name";

myConn.Open(); // <- MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

List<string> exampleStore = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    // Just an example for storing data.
    exampleStore.Add(reader.GetString(0));
}
```

The java version connects to the same server with the same values as I used here, so please don't suggest checking if the server is online.
So the problem must be in my C# code, I noticed `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();`

In the java code. Seems like the driver is made active here, maybe C# needs to do something similar that I'm missing?

Edit: So the connection string should be: string connectionString = string.Format("SERVER={0}; DATABASE={1}; Port={2}; UID={3}; PASSWORD={4};", host, dbName, port, userName, password));

Was using some extra elements from the java version, din't think they would cause these problems. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Have you tried to change the connection string? Try this one: `"Data Source=" + Server_IP + ";" + "User ID=" + Username + ";" + "Password=" + Password + ";"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried it but same error, although it takes a lot longer before the error is shown. Also tried specifiying > "Database=" + dbName < but does'nt work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard connection string is:
`Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`.

Please note that the port is specified separately, with Port=1234, not in the Server field. Also, eliminate `jdbc:mysql:` from the start of the server field, as it's specific to the JDBC driver; use a normal URI string. Nothing else should be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is wrong.

Try:

```
string connectionString = string.Format("SERVER={0}; DATABASE={1}; Port={2}; UID={3}; PASSWORD={4};", host, dbName, port, userName, password));
```

Comment: Thanks this works :), I marked alex as answer because he was first and explained it.